# JQuery Post Callback filter select data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Ich have the following site with JQuery:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Testpost</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 var sendtest = $("#sendtest");
 sendtest.keyup(function(){
      $.post( 
        "test.php",
         { nur: sendtest.val() },
         function(data) {
         $('#receivetest').html(data);
   }
   );
 });
 }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" name="season" id="sendtest"/>
 <div id="receivetest"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And following test.php:

```html
<?php


   $nur = $_POST['nur'];
   echo $nur;


?>
<p id="hello">Hello World!</p>
```

Now I want to see on the receivetest-div only echo $nur; !
What must I do for that?

Comment: What you have gotten right now?

Comment: try to remove <p id="hello">Hello World!</p>

Comment: Have you check console? there is error in console please check

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to code like this. It would be better to add a parameter in your PHP file which will hide the div when you don't need it.

However, you can hide the div like that:

```
$('#receivetest').find('#hello').hide();
```

This will keep the html of the `<div id="hello">` and its content, and hide it to the client.

You can also remove the div by doing this:

```
$('#receivetest').find('#hello').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can the below code

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Testpost</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sendtest = $("#sendtest");
    sendtest.keyup(function(){
         $.post( 
        "asd.php",
         { nur: sendtest.val() },
         function(data) {
         $('#receivetest').html(data);
         $('#receivetest').find('#hello').remove();
            }
         );
    });
    }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="season" id="sendtest"/>
    <div id="receivetest"></div>
</body>
</html>
```